# Creating a Dictionary of 3 Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, object, dictionary

I have 3 arrays:

Name,Company,Description. Each contains 200 strings.

Name=adam,wendy,austin,etc.
Company=saumsung,apple,microsoft,etc.
Description=This employee is good, This Employee works hard, this employee is not good,etc.

I need to connect these three arrays so that when I search and return wendy I can also return what company she works for and her description.

I have researched and it seems that the best way to do this is to combine the 3 arrays into a dictionary with 3 keys: name,company, and description. Could someone point me in the direction how to get started with this? or tell me if maybe a dictionary is not the best method.

All the tutorials I have found have been different in that they have arrays that they want to combine into a dictionary but each array contains values for each key. My keys are already separated.

Comment: Are you asking how to combine them into *one* dictionary?? I can't tell what you're asking here. Also, as a side note, we're here to *guide* you, not write your code for you.

Comment: Sounds like you want an array of arrays, not a dictionary of arrays. You never mentioned what your keys will be for the dictionary.

Comment: @esqew hope my edits clear this up and I didn't ask for you to write my code I asked "for pointers".

Comment: I don't understand what you want. How can you have 3 different values as your keys?

Comment: @Blake - by not providing the code you have tried previously, the community is (usually right in) assuming you have not tried anything yourself and you are posting here to have someone write the code on your behalf.

Comment: @esqew thanks for the tip. check my edit. If this didn't help I guess my knowledge of this subject is too low for even an entry point.

Comment: So you want the employee's name to be the key?

Comment: @crimsonChris I think I want the key to be "name" and the values all of the names. Maybe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of dictionaries,but this makes sense to me.

Comment: I think you are right about not understanding dictionaries.

Comment: You should consider wrapping your company and description into some other object.

Comment: @CrimsonChris what other kind of object would you suggest looking at?

Comment: How about something called EmployeeInfo?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this *example* will help you on your way.

```
NSArray *names;
NSArray *companies;
NSArray *descriptions;
NSMutableDictionary *employeeInfoByName = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (int ii=0; ii<names.count; ++ii) {
    EmployeeInfo *employeeInfo = [[EmployeeInfo alloc] init];
    employeeInfo.company = companies[ii];
    employeeInfo.description = descriptions[ii];
    [employeeInfoByName setObject:employeeInfo forKey:names[ii]];
}
```

Please take the time to understand this code. Don't copy/paste.